# C2065: 'class' undeclared identifier, header included

Tags: c++, header-files, undeclared-identifier

I wanted to run the game by testing the spawner. I thought that I had properly declared the Spawner class by calling its header file in SceneGame.hpp

When I wanted to use the Spawner* as a vector variable, I thought there would be no compiler errors, but I was wrong.

The source of the error comes from declaring the variable vector spawner_list

Relevant files:

Spawner.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

#include "weapon.hpp"
#include "movement.hpp"


// forward declare

class EnemyTemplate;

/*
   Spawner will create enemies and/or power ups

   For spawning enemies, they will recieve one weapon and one movement type

   for powerups, only one will spawn and the spawner would disappear afterwards

   The spawner will create entities through the following:

   Spawn gap: the amount of time to wait between making enemies, in frame ticks
   Spawn limit: the amount of enemies to make before being removed



   */

class Spawner{
private:

    int spawnGapTime;
    int spawnGapSet;

    // If you plan to spawn finite enemies, then use constructor
    int spawnLimit = -1;

    EnemyTemplate* enemyData;
    Weapon* givenWeapon;
    Movement* givenMovement;



    int ticks;

public:

    Spawner(Weapon*, Movement*, EnemyTemplate*, std::vector <int>);

    void update();
    void spawn_enemy();
    void spawn_count();

    ~Spawner(){
        delete givenWeapon;
        delete givenMovement;
        delete enemyData;
    };


};
```

SceneGame.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

#include "scene.hpp"
#include "game.hpp"
#include "entity.hpp"
#include "movement.hpp"
#include "weapon.hpp"
#include "player.hpp"
#include "collisionGrid.hpp"

#include "spawner.hpp"

// forward declare

class BulletTemplate;

class SceneGame : public Scene{
private:

// skipping some code

std::vector <Spawner*> spawner_list; // The source of the error


public:
SceneGame(Game* game);

// skipping some code

};
```

Is there any way I can fix this undeclared identifier problem without having to forward declare Spawner?

Comment: why dont you want to forward declare?

Comment: @dwcanillas I have tried it but I get the no definition error, especially with the implementation, and I do not want it because I have not made a circular dependency

Comment: What is the exact error message? And did you `#include <vector>`?

Comment: It sounds like you should forward declare Spawner in the header and #include in the source

Comment: @dwcanillas Thanks! Now I have to resolve linker problems

Answer (score 1):

```
C2065: 'class' undeclared identifier
```

If that is the literal text of the error message, you're compiling as C, not as C++.

If it isn't the literal text of the error message, you should have posted the literal text of the error message.